# Uncaught (in promise) undefined in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, es6-promise

In google chrome I get this error, but I can't understand what causes it[image: uncaught error]

The `PhotoFloate.getJsonFile()` function correctly returns a promise.

The promise has its `.catch()` code.

Why is that error thrown in line 395?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that `promise.then()` wants *two* arguments, the *resolve()* function and the *reject()* one.

I only had the *resolve()* one.